# How to change element in array at certain index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function that changes an element at the numbered index of an array to a given value.

Here is what I am trying:

```
changeElement = (arr, index, value) => {
  arr.splice(1, 1, 'HEY');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just assign the value without using splice

```
changeElement = (arr, index, value) => {
   arr[index] = value;
}
```